# C# sorting list by int, but by another int if duplicated values are found

Tags: c#

I'm working with a C# list with containing a custom class. The class looks like this;

```
    public class GeneratorLine
    {
        public string TextString { get; set; }
        public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I want to print the "TextString" to a .txt-file, and the linenumber should be the main controller for where the lines are placed in the file. However, duplicated values of linenumbers can occur in which case they should be grouped by "DatabaseId" and placed in the file in this order. If a value is present in "Rank", they should be ordered by this.

I have tried with different constallations of GroupBy, OrderBy etc., but my main problem is that the same "DatabaseId" can have low "Linenumbers" and high "Linenumbers", and a different "DatabaseId" can have "Linenumbers" in between those.

```
Example of file output:
Text1 (DatabaseId: 1, Linenumber: 1, Rank: null)
Text2 (DatabaseId: 1, Linenumber: 2, Rank: null)
Text3 (DatabaseId: 1, Linenumber: 3, Rank: null)
Text4 (DatabaseId: 3, Linenumber: 4, Rank: 1)
Text5 (DatabaseId: 3, Linenumber: 5, Rank: 1)
Text6 (DatabaseId: 3, Linenumber: 6, Rank: 1)
Text7 (DatabaseId: 2, Linenumber: 4, Rank: 2)
Text8 (DatabaseId: 2, Linenumber: 5, Rank: 2)
Text9 (DatabaseId: 2, Linenumber: 6, Rank: 2)
Text10 (DatabaseId: 1, Linenumber: 7, Rank: null)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you add the code which is performing the sort.

Comment: Have you tried ThenBy, e.g. list.OrderBy(x => x.LineNumber).ThenBy(x => x.DatabaseId).ThenBy(x => x.Rank) ?

Comment: Could you clarify where for example a `Linenumber: 5, Rank: null` should be placed in the example list? I don't think the rules you have vaguely explained are enough. Also at the moment `Rank` seems to be tied to `DatabaseId` is this always the case? How are they related? Please provide all relevant information to be able to assist you. That said please provide code of your own attempt(s).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Rank and DatabaseId is not related. Rank is a free field where the user can put in a number. DatabaseId is tied to the Id of the row in the database, and the user cannot edit this. Linenumber: 5, Rank: null should be placed grouped by its DatabaseId.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] **with sample inputs defined in the code** and expected results for those inputs.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the interface [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.8) in your class, such as

```
public class GeneratorLine : IComparable
{
    public string TextString { get; set; }
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Rank { get; set; } // If Rank can be null, its type should be int?

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        GeneratorLine otherLine = obj as GeneratorLine;
        if (otherLine != null)
        {
            // Set by default the comparison between ranks to 0 (meaning they are equals)
            int RankComparison = 0;
            // If both ranks are not null, let's compare them
            if (Rank != null && otherLine.Rank != null)
                RankComparison = (int)this.Rank?.CompareTo(otherLine.Rank);
            // If both ranks are equals or null
            if (RankComparison == 0)
            {
                // compare by LineNumber
                int LineNumberComparison = this.LineNumber.CompareTo(otherLine.LineNumber);
                // if they have same LineNumber
                if (LineNumberComparison == 0)
                {
                    // compare them by DatabaseId
                    return this.DatabaseId.CompareTo(otherLine.DatabaseId);
                }
                // else compare them by LineNumber
                return LineNumberComparison;
            }
            // If both ranks are not null and differents, return their comparison
            return RankComparison;
        }
        else
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a GeneratorLine");
    }

}
```

And then, in your code, simply use :

```
YourCollection.Sort();
```

Where `YourCollection` is your `List<GeneratorLine>`

[Try it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b4bCE3)

Comment: When I do this I get the following error when I try to do .Sort(): Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable.

Comment: Can you show me the line of code where you are using `Sort()` ? Are you doing somehing like `var sorted = MyCollection.Sort();` ?

Comment: Oh, yea it works if I do MyCollection.Sort();. But if no ranks are present, it sorts only by linenumber and not by databaseid. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OOMsSN

Comment: @MathiasJensen I think you need to explain your rules better. The logic behind your sort by linenumber and groupby databaseid is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The proposed solution is correct if ranks are present. If there is no rank for a line, I want it to be come out as the same output as the proposal (https://dotnetfiddle.net/b4bCE3) - there is just no ranks and therefore the databaseid should control the order.

Comment: If DatabaseId 3 has rank 1, i want it to come out before DatabaseId 2 (which has no rank in this example). Right now it gives me this result: https://pastebin.com/N0QyNaK6. But I want this: https://pastebin.com/cRjSz9Z3

Comment: If there are no ranks, I would like this to be the output: https://pastebin.com/Wu8vDCqf

Comment: Why https://pastebin.com/Wu8vDCqf and not https://pastebin.com/UZnwQM2B ?

Comment: Because "Linenumber" should always matter most

Comment: @MathiasJensen Then https://pastebin.com/4Fg8Ea8Z should be the correct output

Comment: @Cid Okay, I see what you mean. Linenumbers should be sorted together if they consecutively, example 4,5,6 but if there are a break in the linenumbers, example 1,2,7 they shouldnt. I hope that it clarifies it.